# Error in coef.lme(m4) : could not find function "coef.lme" with nlme package loaded

Tags: r, nlme

I have the nlme package loaded, however, while     ?coef.lme gives me the description of the function. But then

```
   coef.lme(m4)
   Error in coef.lme(m4) : could not find function "coef.lme"
```

Comment: Just use `coef(m4)`. Generally speaking generic functions for specific classes aren't exported directly from the package. That's how it's shown in the "Examples" section of that help page.

Comment: If you *really* want to call that function you can use `:::`, for example `nlme:::coef.lme`.